# Keychain services broken by code signing

Tags: ios, swift, code-signing, keychain, ios-provisioning

I'm using Keychain Services to save a login token. Everything works as intended in debug builds and Ad-Hoc distribution builds. However in the version of the app downloaded from the app store, it stops working. After a successful initial login attempt, it attempts to request more info from our API, but sends an empty token. The only thing that could be causing this is the token not being saved into the keychain, and is returning the default value (an empty string) when using the token in the request.

So my question is this: How can a different provisioning profile cause the Keychain Service to not be able to save values? I am aware that the two are linked, and that changing the profile will stop you accessing data saved using the previous profile, but this is something different, and I'm completely stumped. It doesn't help that I can't figure out any decent ways to debug a version of an app downloaded from the app store either

Comment: I am having the same problem, but it is that my beta-build with my distribution profile only allows Keychain saving, but crashes every time I try to read from the keychain.  I've tried saving with the same profile but the reading still causes a crash.  This is despite turning Keychain access entitlement on and configuring the plist.

Comment: The SecItemAdd, SecItemCopyMatching, SecItemUpdate APIs return a error code. Can you log this error code and share the same here ? That will help in identifying the cause

Comment: Well an error only occurs when the app is distributed via app store. I can add background keychain saving in next update and see

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out - it's something to do with the swift compiler optimization.

If you go to Build Settings -> Swift Compiler Code Generation -> set Optimization level for release to "None", then the code works.

Comment: No optimisation will make your code really really slow (some find it 100x slower). While -Ofast is not recommended for release, you should consider using -Os

Comment: I have run into the same problem and reported this bug to Apple (bug 19003552 if that's helpful). Anyone running into this should do the same as duplicates should help in prioritizing issues.